# Where can I change "snap to symmetry" tool settings?

Tags: edit-mode, snapping, tools

In Edit Mode, I can do Mesh -> Snap to Symmetry. The operation is performed and I can see the results. However, the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/snap_symmetry.html) shows that there are settings (Direction, Threshold, Factor, Center). I want to change the values of these settings, but I don't know where to find them.

Comment: In the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view)

Comment: Thank you! That works.